Why is the 'limit' limit of maximum recursion depth in python 2**32 / 2 - 31?
In Python, some programs create the error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison or similar.
This is because there is a limit set for how deep the recursion can be nested.
To get the current value for maximum recursion depth, use
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()

The default value seems to be 1000 or 1500 depending on the specific system/python/... combination.
The value can be increased to have access to deeper recursion.
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(LIMIT)

where LIMIT is the new limit.
This is the error that I get when I exceed the 'limit' limit:
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int

Why is the 'limit' limit int(2**32 / 2) - 31?
I would expect that it maybe is int(2**32 / 2) - 1 as it makes sense that integers are signed (32-bit) numbers, but why - 31?
The question first came up as I was testing with 3.9.13 (64-bit). I also tested with 3.12 (64-bit).
Edit: Here is a demo on IDLE with Python 3.9.13.
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> v = 2**31-1
>>> print(v)
2147483647
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.setrecursionlimit(v)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int
>>> v = 2**31-30
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.setrecursionlimit(v)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int
>>> v = 2**31-31
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(v)
>>> 


you might be interested in https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/112282

It is (2**32)/2 - 1, which is 2**31 - 1 i.e. the max value for a signed C integer. Not sure where you got the -31 from. Are you saying that Python on your system complains if you set the limit higher than 2**31 - 31? Mine doesn't: https://i.sstatic.net/keSR2Ub8.png

Did you read the docs? "The highest possible limit is platform-dependent."

Beside the point, but int(x / y) is equivalent to x // y for positive numbers (or at least positive integers in this range).

On a side note: due to the overhead in Python function calling, and how the runtime allocate memory usage around, keep in mind your true limit for recursion will be much lower than that. Maybe you can get  to 100_000 without crashng the runtime - but I would not bet on it.

(ok - in a newer Python I got it to work with 10_million recursion calls with no problems 100_million got me OOM - with older (pre 3.12) around 10_000 would crash the runtime)

@jsbueno Yeah, pure Python recursion is now limited by how much memory you have instead of how large your C stack is. You can do more than 10_000_000 calls per GB if they're lean: Attempt This Online!

I was using this answer for my test.
Until now, I only ran the limit-test on 3.12. Now I also tested the function (ackermann) on it and it seems like both versions also behave differently. In 3.9.13, it seems like it uses the full ~2 billion and actually finishes pretty fast (with no solution). On 3.12, it runs longer than I want to wait for a short test. Maybe it is something like @jhole meant but I am NOT using LRU-cache. In both version it only uses a negligible amount of RAM.

Usually the limit "limit" would be 2**31 - 1, i.e. the max value for a signed C integer (although the highest possible limit is documented as being platform-dependent).
The lower usable range you get within IDLE is because it wraps the built-in function to impose a lower limit:
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit
<function setrecursionlimit at 0xcafef00d>
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit.__wrapped__
<built-in function setrecursionlimit>

This is specific to IDLE, and you should see the "full" 2**31-1 depth when using the same interpreter on the same platform otherwise.
You can find the monkeypatch here in CPython sources:
Lib/idlelib/run.py:install_recursionlimit_wrappers
Usable values are reduced by RECURSIONLIMIT_DELTA=30, and a comment on wrapper function references bpo-26806 (IDLE not displaying RecursionError tracebacks and hangs), where Terry J. Reedy mentions the reason for patching a lower limit:

IDLE adds it own calls to the call stack before (and possibly after) running user code

You should also see that in the docstring:


One question unanswered here is why a C int is required in the first place.  Python is implemented in C so perhaps it's not surprising.

help(sys.setrecursionlimit) would work as well, right?

@nocomment right.

@MarkRansom Yep - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.4/Python/ceval.c#L235-L252

Out of curiosity I checked to see what PyPy do here, since they have no real reason to use a C int. On PyPy they silently cap you to 1M!  https://github.com/pypy/pypy/blob/ee168f24bdf107e4e3242012e276902d20414bc4/pypy/module/sys/vm.py#L62-L67

Another question is, why it does not use unsigned instead of signed.

Especially as only numbers >= 1 are allowed.
